# which is faster sending hidden form data or getting data from database

Tags: php, database, forms, security, hidden

I'm using hidden form to send value. With a submit button.

Its like:

```
<form action="users.php?action=edit" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Josh" size="20" maxlength="19"/>
<input type="submit" name="done" value="Done"/>
</form>
```

And i'm using these values in the next form i'm creating. I don't know which will be better, doing it like this or by getting data from database. Also, which will be more secure ?

Comment: another options sessions another cookies. also maxlength and size on hidden input it pointless

Comment: I would suggest sessions. Forms can be hijacked, db can be slow sometimes (depending on volume of data retrieved, visitors, etc).
Sessions are my favorite so far. No need to save/store anything to db until last step of the proccess.

Comment: Of course, Sessions are problematic when you start to consider scaling and webfarms.

Comment: Thank you for your views and of course the maxlength and size on hidden input. Dagon n andrew n podiluska. I think i'm gonna use sessions. Will it be faster n safer both?

Answer (score 2):

Speed is variable.

The more important question is what is safer: If you store the information on the form, it could be changed by a malicious user.

Never trust any data that comes from a web form - always check and verify it.

I remember one, possibly apocryphal, story about how an early web store stored their prices on a hidden field on a form, and were delighted with the level of sales, only to discover that those sales had been made at a much reduced price due to field meddling by devious consumers.

See http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/43/2/

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from database is more secure as the data cannot be tampered.
If you will put it in a hidden field it will display the value of the php variable which can be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Josh" is the user to be edited and only the logged in "Josh" user can do that. If you would not hesitate to show the data in the hidden field to the user, you can use the hidden field.

Be aware that a user can tamper with the values in the form fields. Everything the user can add to/change in the HTTP request needs to be validated on your server (if it's a reasonable value, if the user actually has the right to edit "Josh" etc.)

In your example there is not really a reason to use the hidden field though:

```
<form action="users.php?action=edit&first_name=Josh" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="done" value="Done"/>
</form>
```

About the speed: For little data, the hidden field version would probably be faster since you avoid a whole roundtrip to the database (Connecting, Transaction, Disconnecting). PHP does not keep a connection pool and connecting to a database is expensive.

Comment: Presumably the OP will connect to the database anyway to update the values?

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's getting data from the database
first people can manipulate datas and secound i guess your db is localhost or in the same network - that makes is faster then sending it over the internet and secure!